# Comparing dates inside a nstimer selector

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, datetime, nsdate

I am writing a countdowtimer application like the timer tab in the clock app of the iPhone. Right now I am having trouble comparing to dates, the 'now' and 'futureDate'. 
all the variables are synthesized and are nonatomic and retain.
I have this code right now.

```
- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"startTimer");
    pickerView.hidden = YES;
    labelView.hidden  = NO;
    now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    futureDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:picker.countDownDuration sinceDate:now];
    NSLog(@"Dates.\nNow = (%@)  \nfutureDate (%@)", now, futureDate);
    timerLabelUpdater = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(labelUpdater) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)labelUpdater {
    if ([now timeIntervalSinceDate:futureDate] < 0.0) {
        NSLog(@"YES\nDates.\nNow = (%@)  \nfutureDate (%@)", now, futureDate);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NO\nNow = (%@)  \nfutureDate (%@)", now, futureDate);
    }
}
```

Debugger info:
2011-02-08 16:46:02.449 App[22504:207] startTimer
2011-02-08 16:46:02.451 App[22504:207] Dates.
Now = (2011-02-08 18:46:02 +0000)
futureDate (2011-02-08 18:47:02 +0000)
2011-02-08 16:46:03.451 App[22504:207] YES

And it stay giving me yes "forever".
But if you see the variable hours, they are +2h in the future compared from my clock time. Is this the bug?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my if was testing the wrong date, comparing the variable now and futureDate the time interval will be the same forever. I replaced the now variable for a [[NSDate alloc] init] in the test. Right now the code works.

```
if ([[[NSDate alloc]init] timeIntervalSinceDate:futureDate] < 0.0) {
    NSLog(@"YES\nDates.\nNow = (%@)  \nfutureDate (%@)", now, futureDate);
} else {
    NSLog(@"NO\nNow = (%@)  \nfutureDate (%@)", now, futureDate);
}
```

sorry for the stupid question.